# Combine Mongo Documents after multiple lookups in single aggregation

Tags: arrays, mongodb, aggregation

I'm stuck trying to combine my document results. Here is my query and data

```
{"_id":"5c21ab13d03013b384f0de26",
"roles":["5c21ab31d497a61195ce224c","5c21ab4ad497a6f348ce224d","5c21ab5cd497a644b6ce224e"],
"agency":"5b4ab7afd6ca361cb38d6a60","agents":["5b4ab5e897b24f1c4c8e3de3"]}
```

Here is the query

```
  return db.collection('projects').aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      agents: ObjectId(agent)
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$agents"
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "agents",
      localField: "agents",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "agents"
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: {
      path: "$roles",
      preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true
    }
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "roles",
      localField: "roles",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "roles"
    }
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "agencies",
      localField: "agency",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "agency"
    }
  }
])
```

As you can see, an entry in the project collection has two arrays that are unwound before a lookup on each entry is performed and then a final lookup is performed on the "agency" field.

However when I get the results from this query I am getting a document count equal to the number of roles. For example the project I am aggregating has 3 roles and 1 agent. So I am getting back an array of 3 objects, one for each role rather than a single document with the roles array containing all three roles. There is also a chance the agents array can have more than one value.

So lost...

Comment: Could you post the sample documents from all the collections

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to run `$unwind` before [$lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup). The `localField` section states that:

> If your localField is an array, you may want to add an $unwind stage to your pipeline. Otherwise, the equality condition between the localField and foreignField is foreignField: { $in: [ localField.elem1, localField.elem2, ... ] }

So basically if you don't run `$unwind` for instance on `roles` then instead of document per role you will get an array of `roles` as `ObjectIds` replaced by an array of objects from that second collection.

So you can try following aggregation:

```
db.collection('projects').aggregate([
    {
        $match: {
            agents: ObjectId(agent)
        }
    },
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: "agents",
            localField: "agents",
            foreignField: "_id",
            as: "agents"
        }
    },
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: "roles",
            localField: "roles",
            foreignField: "_id",
            as: "roles"
        }
    },
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: "agencies",
            localField: "agency",
            foreignField: "_id",
            as: "agency"
        }
    }
])
```

Comment: we just became best friends.